# Updating a txt file of variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

So my challenge today.

I have a config file (really just a txt document) that stores variables to store information passed between scripts or to be used after restarts.

I am looking for a more efficient way to read and update the file. Currently I read the file with:

```
Get-Content $current\Install.cfg | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable -Name line -Value $_
    $a, $b = $line.Split('=')
    Set-Variable -name $a -Value $b
}
```

But to overwrite the contents, I recreate the file with:

```
ECHO OSV=$OSV     >>"$ConfigLoc\tool.cfg"
ECHO OSb=$OSb     >>"$ConfigLoc\tool.cfg"
ECHO cNum=$cNum   >>"$ConfigLoc\tool.cfg"
ECHO cCode=$cCode >>"$ConfigLoc\tool.cfg"
ECHO Comp=$Comp   >>"$ConfigLoc\tool.cfg"
```

Each time I have added a new saved variable, I have just hardcoded the new variable into both the original config file and the config updater.
As my next updates require an additional 30 variables to my current 15. I would like something like:

```
Get-Content $current\Install.cfg | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable -Name line -Value $_
    $a, $b = $line.Split('=')
    ECHO $a=$$a
}
```

Where `$$a` uses the variable $a in the loop as the variable name to load the value.
Best example i can show to clarify is:

```
   ECHO $a=$$a    (in current loop)
   Echo OSV=$OSV  (actually appears in code as)
```

Not sure how to clarify this anymore, or how to achieve it with the variable title also being a variable.

Comment: You probaly should take a look at `hashtables`. (https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/)

Comment: Hashtables, and `Export-CliXML` or `ConvertTo-JSON | set-content`. Don't reinvent the serializing data to disk wheel, and don't go for this "how to achieve it with the variable title also being a variable" - this is terrible for maintenance and expandability, as you're finding. Hashtables and other collections are the fix for this.

Comment: Part of the reason I have been using this current method is I also have a batch file that retrieves the data. It looks like `Export-CliXML` is the method which solves the problem for powershell, but is it even possible for batch to read those files? 
If not, I might just be making the 5 variables in a cfg file for the batch and everthing else in the `Hashtables`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a file that has name=value parameters, here's an alternate suggestion.  This is a snippet of a real script I use every day.  You might modify it so it reads your .csv input and uses it instead of the hard coded values.

```
$Sites = ("RawSiteName|RoleName|DevUrl|SiteID|HttpPort|HttpsPort", `
    "SiteName|Name of role|foo.com|1|80|443" `    
     ) | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter "|"

   $site = $sites[0]
   Write-Host "RawSiteName =$($site.RawSiteName)"
```

You might be able to use something similar to `$text = Get-Content MyParameters.csv` and pipe that to the `ConvertFrom-CSV` cmdlet.  I realize it's not a direct answer to what you are doing but it will let you programmatically create a file to pass across scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you're looking for **variable indirection**: accessing a variable *indirectly*, via its name stored in *another* variable.

In PowerShell, **[`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable)** allows you to do that, as demonstrated in the following:

```
# Sample variables.
$foo='fooVal'
$bar='barVal'

# List of variables to append to the config file -
# the *names* of the variables above.
$varsToAdd = 
  'foo',
  'bar'

# Loop over the variable names and use string expansion to create <name>=<value> lines.
# Note how Get-Variable is used to retrieve each variable's value via its *name*.
$(foreach ($varName in $varsToAdd) {
  "$varName=$(Get-Variable $varName -ValueOnly)"
}) >> "$ConfigLoc/tool.cfg"
```

With the above, the following lines are appended to the output `*.cfg` file:

```
foo=fooVal
bar=barVal
```

---

Note that you **can *read* such a file more easily with the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata), which outputs a *hashtable* with the name-value pairs from the file**:

```
$htSettings = Get-Content -Raw "$ConfigLoc/tool.cfg" | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Accessing `$htSettings.foo` would then return `fooVal`, for instance.

---

**With a *hashtable*** as the settings container, ***updating* the config file becomes easier**, as you can simply **recreate the file with *all* settings and their current values**:

```
$htSettings.GetEnumerator() |
  ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } > "$ConfigLoc/tool.cfg"
```

<sup>Note: PowerShell by default doesn't enumerate the entries of a hashtable in the pipeline, which is why `.GetEnumerator()` is needed.</sup>

---

Generally, though, **this kind of manual serialization is fraught**, as others have pointed out, and there are more robust - though typically less friendly - alternatives.

With your string- and line-based serialization approach, there are two things to watch out for:

- All values are saved as a *strings*, so you have to manually reconvert to the desired data type, if necessary - and even possible, given that not all objects provide meaningful string representations.

  - Generally, the most robust serialization format is `Export-CliXml`, but note that it is not a *friendly* format - be careful with manual edits.
- `ConvertFrom-StringData` will *fail* with duplicate names in the config file, which means you have to manually ensure that you create no duplicate entries when you append to the file - if you use the above approach of recreating the file from a hashtable every time, however, you're safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. This is the solution I am going with. Importing and exporting couldn't be simpler. If I have to manually update the XML install default I can with ease which is also amazing. I also love the fact that even if you import as `$Test` you can still use `$original` to access variables. I will be creating multiple hashtables to organize the different data I will be using going forward and just import/export it in a `$config` variable as the master.

```
$original = @{
    OSV='0'
    OSb='0'
    cNum='00000'
    cCode='0000'
    Client='Unknown'
    Comp='Unknown'
}

$original | Export-Clixml $Home\Desktop\sample.cfg

$Test = Import-Clixml $Home\Desktop\sample.cfg

Write $Test
Write $original.Client
```

Comment: `Export-CliXml` is indeed the safest way to serialize, but I wouldn't call manually editing the output something that be done with _ease_. Also, it is at odds with your earlier comment that the file must also be readable by a _batch file_. `ConvertFrom-StringData` also gives you the hashtable convenience, but with the original file format (serializing out takes only a bit of manual work - see my update). I encourage you to accept the answer that best addresses your question _as originally asked_.

Comment: Sorry after actually beginning to implement the solution, I decided to go with a PSscript to generate the install.cfg file. Cleaner to sort and update. Also found that each time I updated the file the order changed based on what was updated and what wasn't.
As for the batch, I have opted to generate its own cfg file accordingly. Because I am changing my tool from the ground up, I am having to rethink a lot of the design and batch exists because of some systems I need to do things on that don't support PS5.0 and I'm not allowed to update.

Comment: Understood, but you asked a specific question, and you got a specific answer - that's what future readers benefit from, and to assist them, you should accept the best answer _that addresses the question as asked_ (perhaps needless to say, I think it is mine, but you don't have to agree). That your requirements and thinking changed _after_ asking the question and after _having received answers_ is outside the scope of the question; it's not that adding your new approach is a problem per se - it may _also_ be of interest - but that is separate from picking an answer to the original question.

Comment: In case you're interested in the meta-discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371307/45375